# Should a suspended ceiling be installed before or after drywall?

Tags: ceiling-tiles

We’re putting a small apartment in my garage and want to put in a drop ceiling.    Should we drywall the walls first or put the ceiling in first? I’ve watched several videos and it looks like the tracks are always attached to the drywall

Comment: This is a matter of prerogative and the nuances of your project. Drywall is usually done first as this makes things easier for the drywallers and results in a full angle showing on the ceiling. It certainly doesn't have to be done that way, though.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: sheet or tile ceiling? crown moulding or square corners?

Answer (score 1):

The normal practice is to drywall first.  It would be convenient to tape and mud, finish to your desire and paint the walls as well, prior to hanging the drop ceiling.